# Understanding ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, system-calls, processbuilder

For the second time I had a problem with values extract from system calls using ProcessBuilder.

The last time I used the call:

```
try {
    String[] cmd = new String[5];
    cmd[0] = "reg";
    cmd[1] = "query";
    cmd[2] = key;
    cmd[3] = "/v";
    cmd[4] = name;

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    Process process = pb.start();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(process.getInputStream());

    reader.start();
    int exitValue = process.waitFor();
    reader.join();
    if (exitValue != 0) {
        return null;
    }

    String result = reader.getResult();
    int p = result.indexOf(REGSTR_TOKEN);

    if (p == -1) {
        return null;
    }

    return result.substring(p + REGSTR_TOKEN.length()).trim();
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

To extract a value from windows registry.

But the value always return an error, different from what happens if I make the call from the command line. It's seens that the enviroment variables are differents.

What's the problem? I should set any enviroment variable?

Comment: Yes, your code looks fine: you should be able to read from your Java reader whatever "reg" writes to stdout.  SUGGESTION: 1) run your full command from a command prompt and make sure it's legal.  2) Step through under the debugger.  Examine "result"; compare it with your command-line output.

Comment: An alternative is to use JNA, which has an existing API for interacting with the Windows registry. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java

Comment: Also, check out this: [Read-Write Windows Registry Using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)

Comment: Try supplying the full path to the "reg.exe" command "c:/windows/System32/reg.exe". `ProcessBuilder` does not take into account the system path nor does it "guess" the command extension

Comment: What's `StreamReader`?  I your command (with my own launcher code) and it works fine

Comment: Actually, for something under \windows\system32, I don't think a fully qualified path is necessary (but, of course, it couldn't hurt ;))

Comment: @MadProgrammer, you are right. The ProcessBuilder was calling the wrong REG.exe. This code is not mine, it's from a know application that doesn't works well in Win64!  Thanks

Comment: `StreamReader` is used in a large of code snippet for this solution. I found that the code only copied a know solution for look for in the Windows Registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the Java runtime found the wrong `reg.exe`. When executing as command line, it was executed as `\Windows\System32\reg.exe`, when running inside the process that call my java class calls `\Windows\SysWOW64\reg.exe`. Each `reg.exe` points to differents Registry tables. That was the bug.

The code must be fixed:

```
cmd[0] = "\\Windows\\System32\\reg";
```

Or:

```
cmd[0] = "\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\reg";
```